# Why is GPG-agent still caching my passphrase?

Tags: gnupg, keychain

I can not get gpg to prompt me for my passphrase when I want to decrypt a file. I tried including:

```
default-cache-ttl 0
max-cache-ttl 0
```

(also flipped the bit to 1)

within `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` and then running either:
`gpgconf --reload gpg-agent` or `echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent` or killing the daemon but none of that works.

I wonder if GPG Keychain is doing something wonky under the hood? (Note I am on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6)

```
gpg (GnuPG/MacGPG2) 2.2.10
libgcrypt 1.8.3
```

GPG Keychain `Version 1.4.6 (1514)`

My `gpg.conf`

```
# Avoid information leaked
no-emit-version
no-comments
export-options export-minimal

# Displays the long format of the ID of the keys and their fingerprints
keyid-format 0xlong
with-fingerprint

# Displays the validity of the keys
list-options show-uid-validity
verify-options show-uid-validity

# Limits the algorithms used
personal-cipher-preferences AES256
personal-digest-preferences SHA512
default-preference-list SHA512 SHA384 SHA256 RIPEMD160 AES256 TWOFISH BLOWFISH ZLIB BZIP2 ZIP Uncompressed

cipher-algo AES256
digest-algo SHA512
cert-digest-algo SHA512
compress-algo ZLIB

disable-cipher-algo 3DES
weak-digest SHA1

s2k-cipher-algo AES256
s2k-digest-algo SHA512
s2k-mode 3
s2k-count 65011712
```

My `gpg-agent.conf`

```
# Disable agent cache   
default-cache-ttl 0
max-cache-ttl 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved the issue.
TL:DR GPG Suite was saving the password in macOS Keychain (not GPG Keychain)

More information [here](https://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/kb/faq/password-management).

Comment: Thanks! You saved me some time there!